# Regex replace not working as expected from CLI

Tags: regex, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to work out why this regex won't work. The line in the script I want to edit is:

```
Links::send_email('link_added.eml', $results, { admin_email => 1 }) or die "Unable to send mail: $GT::Mail::error";
```

and replace it with:

```
Links::send_email('link_added.eml', { %$results, %$user }, { admin_email => 1 }) or die "Unable to send mail: $GT::Mail::error";
```

I'm trying to do it with:

```
perl -p -e "s|'link_added.eml', $results|'link_added.eml', { %$link, %$results }|g" /home/zaprwire add.cgi
```

but it always comes up as:

```
Links::send_email('link_added.eml', { %, % }$results, { admin_email => 1 }) or die "Unable to send mail: $GT::Mail::error";
```

Notice $result wasn't replaced, and the { } bit also only has % and not the variable names I need. I've tried escaping with $ etc, but nothing seems to work. What am I missing?

Comment: Try `sed`, `sed -E 's|(link_added\.eml, )\$results|\1{ %$link, %$results }|g'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks - why ( instead of ' around "link_added.eml" ?  Is that just a typo?

Comment: I use a group to shorten the replacement. There seems to be no `'` around `link_added.eml`, that is why they need to be removed.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ahhh ok - yes I see the \1 in there now. That works like a charm. Please mark it as an answer and I will sort =) Still not sure why my other version didn't work though

Comment: You are using the `$link` and `$results` in double quotes, so variable expansion takes place.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ah yes that makes sense. I was using ' but then changed to " due to having ' in the regex as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `$link` and `$results` in double quotes, so variable expansion takes place.

I would recommend using `sed` here since the search and replace here is rather basic:

```sh
sed -E 's|(link_added\.eml, )\$results|\1{ %$link, %$results }|g' /home/zaprwire add.cgi
```

Note the single quotes around the `sed` command. Also, there seems to be no `'` around `link_added.eml`, that is why they need to be removed.

I added a capturing group in the pattern to shorten the replacement pattern.

And remember to escape `.` if you plan to match a literal dot.

**More details**

- `(link_added\.eml, )` - `link_added.eml,` and a space captured into Group 1 (`\1` refers to this value from the replacement pattern)
- `\$results` - a literal `$results` string